# How can I scrape an ebay-webpage with BeautifulSoup that I previously got by browser automation via Selenium?

Tags: html, selenium, dom, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape ebay. Before any scraping occurs, I want to automate search, filtering and sorting of the ebay-posts by automating the clicking needed for it with selenium. I have managed to (relatively robustly) get to the page I want, however it seems that there are problems with (1) webpage changing its code and/or (2) the transition to the BeautifulSoup part.

(1): Sometimes, when I search for an item on ebay on the browser and inspect the webpage, the class for the unsorted list (ul) that describes all ebay-articles on the page has a class name "ListInnerView" but some other times its "srp-results". In addition, it seems that many class and id names change from the structure "lv(followed by a string)" to "s-item__(followed by a string)", so the whole page seems to change in a way.

(2): When I look a the html-code that BeautifulSoup reveices (It should request the url that Selenium ended up with, which is specific), the class and id names don't match the ones I can see in the webdriver. It is the exact difference of names that you see in (1).

I don't know what to do if the html-code from webdriver window doesn't match the one that BeautifulSoup receives. Because then I cannot visually locate the elements that BeautifulSoup should find.

I have been searching the web for explanations/solutions of my problem and didn't find one yet, hence the question.

Here the significant parts of my code (if info is missing, i can also share the whole code):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("https://www.ebay.de")
>a bunch of clicking, hovering and scrolling, that works<

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
>a bunch of finding elements, doesn't work; works on its own though, using specific set of class(id-names...
```